# How can I interact with a SQLite or MySQL database?

Tags: ide

This might be more suitable for IDE, not for Vim, but still I would appreciate if there was a way that would allow me to connect to either local or remote MySQL/SQLite databases. Is there such a way to do this?

I think it could be placed in a split window or in its own tab. I would want to read, update, delete rows, import/export sql. Some advanced features like foreign keys could be, obviously, omitted.

Comment: I know [this plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) from a colleague who worked with it. I know this plugin works but I don't personnaly have enough experience to give you some precises informations about it.

Comment: Basic vim will not work for what you want because it is built to edit text. What people normally do is to have a terminal/console open in parallel to execute those commands. But you might try neovim if you really need to have a terminal running inside vim...

Answer (score 3):

Even though I agree with @Vitor's comment saying that Vim is not meant to interact with a database, here is another solution:

Tim Pope recently released [vim-dadbod](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod) that he calls "a more modern take on dbext.vim"

> ```
> DB is a Vim plugin for interacting with databases.
> It's a more modern take on dbext.vim, improving on it on the following ways:
>
>     - Connections are specified with a single URL, rather than prompting you
>       for 14 separate variables
>     - All interaction is through invoking :DB, not 53 different commands and 35
>       different maps (omitting many of the more esoteric features, of course)
>     - Supports a modern array of backends, including NoSQL databases:
>         - MongoDB
>         - MySQL
>         - PostgreSQL
>         - Redis
>         - Sqlite
>         - Your own easily implemented adapter
>     - Easily configurable based on a project directory (as seen in rails.vim, for example),
>       rather than just globally or in a per-file modeline
> ```

From what I tested the postgresql integration works fine, given the usual quality of Pope's plugins there's a chance that it is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm myself trying to work it out these days. I think [dbext](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) might help.

You can find many third-parties from [vim-scripts](https://github.com/vim-scripts) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, [dbext](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) is probably what you are looking for.  I've been using it for a while now to run queries against a (an?) SQL Server database.  I've only used it for simple querying of stuff, but I believe it can insert, update, delete, etc.